# I want to know the meaning of this phrase in assembly language

Tags: database, assembly, dup

i am supposed to code a loop that moves zeros to each byte of DATE_TBL:
         DATE_TBL DB 25 DUP(?)

But i am not sure what the code DB 25 DUP (?) does
I know DUP means duplicate
and DB means define byte

Answer (score 0):

25 DUP(?) is the same as to write '?' (=any value) 25 times. Thus 'DB 25 DUP(?)' means 'reserve address space for 25 bytes with any (don't care) value'.

Note, that if those 'DUP(?)' would go to initialized data segment, it will be the same as 25 zero bytes (and they probably would occupy space on the disk too). But if they are in uninitialized one, the space would be reserved by OS loader only (and not necessarily initialized at all - it's OS dependent).